# Weird Javascript behavior in Array.map

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider this code:

```js
var functions = []
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    functions.push(function() {
        console.log(i)
    })
}

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    functions[i]()
}

//outputs: 
// 1
// 2
// 3


functions.map(function(fn, i) {
    fn()
})

//outputs: 
// 3
// 3
// 3
```

Why is the output different between the for loop and array.map?
Each function in functions array should output the value 3, this is the typical behavior i would expect from my knowledge in Javascript...

Comment: Your second `for` loop is confusing the issue because it reuses (and overwrites) the `i` variable all your functions refer to. Try `i = "hello"; functions[0]();`.

Comment: I second that, and would like to add that the map function defines a new i variable as it opens a new scope. It therefore does not overwrite the original i variable and the output is 3, as you would expect

Comment: try fn(i) i your code